# How do I analyse an execution path?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xsd

I'm trying to debug a Visual Studio extension that uses a combination of C#, XML, XSD & XSLT. It has about 2m LOC spread across 2000+ files.

I want to trace the functional flows. 
How can I find out which parts of the code are being executed as I select a sequence of steps in the user interface?

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlogtracelistener?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio provides a debugging feature. F5 or (Debug > Start Debugging) is first step to initiate debugging. F9 or (Debug > Start Debugging > Toggle Break) is a marker for debugger to stop if application runs in debug mode.

Like SQL database, Visual Studio doesn't provide execution path of any application.

Since Visual Studio doesn't provide any execution path. You should visit architecture document that provides details of design and architecture of application. It helps to understand the application whereas debugging helps to understand the code.

How to debug : Since you have 2M LOC and 2000+ files. You should go to the entry point of the application, start marking break points to core functions. F5 will help to run application and it stops at break point that comes first of the execution sequence. You can do step by step debug using F10 and F11. Again F5 to run further and it stops at next break point on execution sequence. And so on.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I'm familiar with the VS debugging featuresUnfortunately there is more than one "entry point" because the app

Comment: Mark all entry points with breaks and debug the app. Since it is quite a huge app, make a notes of each entry point as debug. It helps in long run.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I'm familiar with the VS debugging features. Unfortunately there is more than one "entry point" because the functionality is spread across multiple C# files many of which call XSLT files that are used for transforms. The adjective that comes to mind to describe the code is "labyrinthine".
This is why I'm looking for an alternative way of discovering the execution paths as I use the tool.
What would be very useful is a tool that tells me which part of the code base is being called when I use one of the many functions in the user interface.
Any clues?